# awk argument to in print specific matched value in a file

Tags: awk

Hi I need to rearrange a data file I have using `awk`. Below is my data for example:

```
A1;1234 B1;4556 C1;5673 D1;0987
A1;1524 B1;8545 D1;81535
A1;2035 C1;52134 D1;95412
B1;5135 C1;5513 D1;5722
```

If i wanted to print only the data on the field which contains only `C1`; How can I do it on `awk`?

Expected output:

```
C1;5673
              <------ "This line is really blank since there is no C1;
C1;52134
C1;5513
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the `awk` command would attain your goal,

```
$ awk '{if($0 ~ /C1/){match($0,/C1;[^ ]+/);print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)} else print ""}' file
C1;5673

C1;52134
C1;5513
```

Brief explanation,

1. `if($0 ~ /C1/)`: find the records include C1
2. `match($0,/C1;[^ ]+/)`: locate the pattern meets the regex `C1;[^ ]+`, and the start point would be stored in RSTART, and the length would be in RLENGTH
3. `substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)`: print the sub-string start from `RSTART` which length is `RLENGTH`

Comment: Thank you so much CWLiu!  This one is working great! Thanks for your help

Comment: @terence, glad it can help. Please kindly set the check to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Short ***gawk*** solution:

```
awk -v FPAT='C1;[0-9]+' '{ print $1 }' file
```

The output:

```
C1;5673

C1;52134
C1;5513
```

---

- `-v FPAT='C1;[0-9]+'` - pattern, defining field value

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$0 !~ /C1/ {$0 = ""} {match($0,/C1;[^ ]+/);print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file
```

1. Checking for the case when C1 is not present in the line and assigning $0 = ""
2. If the pattern existsm we will go to the next block and do the processing to extract and print C1 substring.

Output:

```
C1;5673

C1;52134
C1;5513
```

Comment: Thanks Ramakanth Putta for the support, this is also working fine.  Almost similar to CWLiu answer.. thank you so much for your great help!

Answer (score 0):

Input

```
$ cat file
A1;1234 B1;4556 C1;5673 D1;0987
A1;1524 B1;8545 D1;81535
A1;2035 C1;52134 D1;95412
B1;5135 C1;5513 D1;5722
```

Output

```
$ awk '{ print match($0, /C1;[0-9]+/) ? substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) : ""}' file
C1;5673

C1;52134
C1;5513
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your support!